# Why the content is centered when padding-left and margin-left rules are set to zero?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

In a Wordpress theme, the posts content is justified to the center of the parent layer. The problem is that I don't know how to justify it to the left. Here is an example of the relevant HTML:

```
<div id="content" role="main">
  <div id="post-329" class="post-329 news type-news status-publish hentry category-house category-techno has-post-thumbnail">
      <div class="notice-content">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is what I can see with Firebug:

|   layer | ====> | calculated property |

| #content | =>  | margin-left: 121px | & | padding-left: 0 |

| #post-329 | =>  | margin-left: 0 | & | padding-left: 0 |

| .notice-content | =>  | margin-left: 0 | & | padding-left: 0 |

and no `text-align` property. But every post content is centered.

¿What can be doing the posts to be justified to the center and how to avoid it?

**Edit:**

Finally found out the issue. The `hentry` class had `margin: 0 auto;`. This causes the content to be centered. What I still don't understand is why Firebug indicate the `margin-left` as `0px`, when actually it is `auto` and not zero.

Comment: How about `.notice-content { text-align: left; }`?

Comment: @kleinfreund - Nothing changes.

Comment: margin auto values will get calculated by the browser. Not very unusual it's `0`.

Comment: @kleinfreund - And why Firebug displays zeros like calculated values when they are actually not zero?

Comment: They're zero, if it says so. You're not inspecting the correct element then.

Comment: `auto` is not a length as such, it's just an indication that says the browser will need to calculate what the value actually will be. What you're looking at, the resulting calculated value, is always 0px for blocks (unless you set the width as well).